# Gummiboot on an ext2 partition

Tags: uefi

Apparently gummiboot requires a Fat32 partition, but can the ext2 driver that comes with rEFIND be used with gummiboot so that it can be booted from an ext2 partition?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes, but you'll need to experiment, and the solution may be ugly or require a lot of work. A few approaches spring to mind:

- The generic EFI user interface provided by Tianocore includes options to load drivers. This interface is used by VirtualBox and DUET, but the only hardware I know of that uses it is the Minnowboard. I've never seen a similar option in a regular PC, so as a practical matter this is unlikely to work. (I've also never tested this feature, so I don't know if it would properly bind the drivers once they're loaded.)
- You could experiment with `efibootmgr` in Linux and/or `bcfg` in an EFI shell to load the driver from a FAT partition as the first boot option, with gummiboot on the ext2fs partition as a second option. I'm skeptical that this would bind the driver to the filesystem(s), though, so I suspect this wouldn't work. I might be wrong, though. If it did work, the driver would load and exit, and the EFI would then launch gummiboot.
- An EFI shell script could load the driver, bind it to the filesystem(s), and then launch any program you like from the ext2fs partition. I'm pretty confident that this would work. On most computers, you'd need to install an EFI shell program as the default boot program. The big problem is that the EFI shell binaries I've seen all seem to impose a delay on startup to give you the option to *not* run the `startup.nsh` startup script, so this would slow down the boot process.
- You could write a custom program that loads the driver, binds it to your filesystem(s), and then launches whatever program you like. In fact, rEFInd can do this job; however, that would be overkill, and the question then becomes: Why use rEFInd to launch gummiboot? If you have the skill to write the customized program, it would almost certainly be easier to modify gummiboot to load the ext2fs driver and then launch a kernel from an ext2fs partition.

All of these approaches would require putting the ext2fs driver (and an EFI shell or custom driver-loading program) on the normal FAT ESP. The only way to rid yourself of the ESP, if that's your goal, is to build your own custom firmware with built-in ext2fs support. (I suppose that could be another bullet-list item, but it would be a *lot* of work for a very minor benefit.)

A logical question at this point becomes: Why do you want to use gummiboot rather than rEFInd? rEFInd has most of gummiboot's capabilities and many more of its own, so it may be that rEFInd will do what you need. If you dislike the graphical display, you can set the `textonly` option in `refind.conf` to get a text-mode display similar to gummiboot's.

Comment: Thanks Rod for a really detailed reply; yes, it was your final assumption that was driving me: I was looking for something simple and without a GUI.  I wasn't aware that I could run rEFind in text-mode so, clearly, that's the best way forward for me.  Thanks again.